# How to add chars to String value at specific intervals in Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, if-statement

Ii am having trouble my below code I am building a project which requires the user to input `"This is some \"really\" great. (Text)!?"` which is then converted into `THISISSOMEREALLYGREATTEXT` and the value is passed into the next parameter. then in my Obify method I am attempting to add OB in front of every vowel `AEIOUY` but in my function it does not do this effectively, it prints out `THISISSOMEREALLYGREATTEXT` numerous times and with each new time it passes `THISISSOMEREALLYGREATTEXT` it adds in OB at the end when I need OB infront of every vowel instead of just at the end. please do show me where I am going wrong so I can continue to progress. once again thank you in advance and the code under review is below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void  main(String[] args) {
    normalizeText();
    obify("THISISSOMEREALLYGREATTEXT" );

}

// Part 1 Normalized Method to convert all letter to uppercase and removing all special characters and placing it into String codey.

public static String normalizeText (){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    String normText;

    System.out.println("Please input text to encrypt");
    normText = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println(normText.replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toUpperCase());


    return normText;


}

//This method will take in the Normalized text and insert a capital O and B in-front of every vowel and return the text
private static String obify (String input) {

    String obifiledInput = input;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input.contains( Character.toString( input.charAt( i ) ) )) {
            obifiledInput = obifiledInput + "OB" + Character.toString( input.charAt( i ) );
        } else {
            obifiledInput = obifiledInput + Character.toString( input.charAt( i ) );
        }
            System.out.println(obifiledInput);
    }
    return obifiledInput;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your `obify` function, I don't quite see where it is that you are checking if the `Character` is a vowel. What the following code:

```
if (input.contains( Character.toString( input.charAt( i ) ) ))
```

is doing is checking if `input` contains a character at a certain position in `input`. That doesn't quite solve your problem of checking if the letter is a vowel. Additionally, you are setting `obifiledInput` to `input` directly without first going through and adding the `OB` when required. To fix these problems, you can try my code below:

```
private static String obify (String input) {
    String obifiledInput = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char temp = input.charAt(i);
        if (char == 'A' || char == 'E' || char == 'I' || char == 'O' || char == 'U') {
            obifiledInput += "OB" + temp;
        } else {
            obifiledInput += "" + temp;
        }
    }
    return obifiledInput;
}
```

I think that you should find that this works. It checks if the character is a vowel, `["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]`. Then, it adds `"OB"` and the character to `obifiledInput`. Otherwise, it just adds the `Character`. Finally, it returns the `String` that has been "obified".

Comment: Thank you for this I have understood in full where I was wrong your explanation was very detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Just match input.charAt(i) with all the vowels it should do fine. Also there is a small mistake in your code, you have initialized oblifiedInput with input and then you are adding OB to that string. Even if your for loop was correct it still would have not resulted in the required output.

```
private static String obify (String input) {

   String obifiledInput = "";
   char c;
   for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
       c=input.charAt(i);
       if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u') {
           obifiledInput +="OB";
       }
       obifiledInput +=c;
   }
   System.out.println(obifiledInput);
   return obifiledInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use an array of *char*, pass said array into a *for each* structure, and then use the [`replaceAll​(String regex, String replacement)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method on your String?

Plus, there is the risk of having the 'O' of "OB" being considered as another vowel of the code; so 'O' will have to be the first vowel to be checked.

It would give something around the line of:

```
String obifiledInput = input;
ArrayList<Character> vowels = { 'O', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'U', 'Y' };

for (char curr_char : vowels) {
    obifiledInput.remplaceAll( "[" + curr_char + "]", "OB" + curr_char)

    System.out.println(obifiledInput);  
}

return obifiledInput;
```